# Which method does pandas use for percentile?

Tags: pandas, percentile, quartile

I was trying to understand lower/upper percentiles calculation in pandas and got a bit confused. Here is the sample code and output for it.

```
test = pd.Series([7, 15, 36, 39, 40, 41])
test.describe()
```

output:

[image]

I am interested in only 25%, 75% percentiles.
I wonder which method does pandas use to calculate them?

Referring to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quartile the article, results are different as following:

[image]

So what statistical/mathematical method does pandas uses to calculate percentile?

Comment: [pd.Series.quantile](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.quantile.html)? or [pd.DataFrame.quantile](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.quantile.html)?

Comment: @Abdou 
No. I mean within .describe() method. And actually, <'pd.Series.quantile>

Comment: Also related http://stackoverflow.com/q/38596100/2285236

Comment: @ayhan thanks for the comment, yes it is related a bit, unfortunately unanswered.

Comment: @NatigAliyev, take a look at `quantile` with `from pandas.core.algorithms import quantile`. That `quantile` function has an `interpolation_method` parameter; if that helps at all. It may also be linked to [`numpy's percentile method`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-dev/reference/generated/numpy.percentile.html).

Comment: @Abdou I really appreciate for your help. I used quantile and tried several examples and finally figured that out how python mathematically calculate quantile/percentile.

Comment: @NatigAliyev, that sounds great. Would you mind sharing your solution here, so we can all benefit from your findings?

Comment: @Abdou I posted my answer. Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comments, I finally figured out how it works by trying `from pandas.core.algorithms import quantile` using `quantile` function as @Abdou suggested.

I am not that good to explain it only by typing, therefore I will do it only on the given example for 25% and 75% for this example only. Here is the brief (maybe poor) explanation:

For the example list `[7, 15, 36, 39, 40, 41]` quantiles are following way:

7 -> 0%

15 -> 20%

36 -> 40%

39 -> 60%

40 -> 80%

41 -> 100%

Since we want to find 25% percentile, it will be between 15 and 36, moreover, it is 20% + 5% = 15 + (36-15)/4 = 15 + 5.25 = 20.25.

(36-15)/4 is used, because the distance between 15 and 36 is 40% - 20% = 20%, so we divide it by 4 to get 5%.

The same way we can find 75%.

60% + 15% = 39 + 3*(40-39)/4 = 39.75

That's it. I am really sorry for poor explanation

NOTE: Thank you @shin for the correction mentioned in the comment.

Comment: 20% + 5% = 15 + (36-15)/4 = 15 + 5.5 = 20.5 should be 20.25.

Answer (score 1):

It does a `[series.quantile(x) for x in percentiles]` where percentiles is `percentiles = np.array([0.25, 0.5, 0.75])` if it s not provided.

You can see that in [pandas/pandas/core/generic.py](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/362e78d944cc72d9da95c7feb0e7d385a63beeae/pandas/core/generic.py)

So it is using : http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.quantile.html

Comment: thanx for response. Actually I am asking for statistical method it is using? what statistical method it uses to calculate 25% and 75% percentiles