# np.percentile does not seem to be giving the correct output

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, statistics, data-science

I have a below list.

33, 26, 24, 21, 19, 20, 18, 18, 52, 56, 27, 22, 18, 49, 22, 20, 23, 32, 20, 18

All I am trying is to find the the 25th Percentile.

I used simple numpy program to find it.

```
import numpy as np
arr = [33, 26, 24, 21, 19, 20, 18, 18, 52, 56, 27, 22, 18, 49, 22, 20, 23, 32, 20, 18]
np.percentile(arr,25)
```

Output is : 19.75

But If we count is manually or Use Excel the 25th percentile comes as 19.25.

[image]

I expect the output as 19.25 but the actual output from numpy is 19.75. Can someone please help what is wrong here?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python equivalent of Excel's PERCENTILE.EXC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38596100/python-equivalent-of-excels-percentile-exc)

Answer (score 2):

You see, in excel there's two percentile function: `PERCENTILE.EXC` and `PERCENTILE.INC` and the difference is in "*the `Percentile.Inc` function the value of k is is within the range 0 to 1 inclusive, and in the `Percentile.Exc` function, the value of k is within the range 0 to 1 exclusive.*" ([source](https://www.excelfunctions.net/excel-percentile-exc-function.html))

Numpy's `percentile` function computes the k'th percentile where k must be between 0 and 100 **inclusive** ([docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.percentile.html))

Let's check that.

[image: Difference beetwen INC and EXC excel's PERCENTILE functions]

```
arr = [18, 18, 18, 18, 19, 20, 20, 20, 21, 22, 22, 23, 24, 26, 27, 32, 33, 49, 52, 56]
np.percentile(arr,25)
```

> 19.75

Hope that helps

Answer (score 1):

Check your input values, and lookup what excel uses, since these are the options in numpy

```
t = ['linear', 'lower', 'higher', 'nearest', 'midpoint']    
arr = np.array([33, 26, 24, 21, 19, 20, 18, 18, 52, 56, 27, 22, 18, 49, 22, 20, 23, 32, 20, 18])
    for cnt, i in enumerate(t):
        v = np.percentile(arr, 25., interpolation=i)
        print("type: {} value: {}".format(i, v))

    type: linear value: 19.75
    type: lower value: 19
    type: higher value: 20
    type: nearest value: 20
    type: midpoint value: 19.5
```